# Create 3rd Table SQL with difference of 2 other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Afternoon all

I am trying to create a view with 3 tables.

```
Create view breakdown as
SELECT x.month_
     , x.returns_
     , y.sales_
     , z.profit_
FROM
  (SELECT SUM(Return_Value_Eur) AS returns_
        , monthname(Return_Date) AS month_
   FROM returns
   GROUP BY month_) x
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT SUM(Total_Price_Eur) AS sales_
        , monthname(Order_Date) AS month_
   FROM orders
   GROUP BY month_) y ON x.month_ = y.month_
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT (SUM(Total_Price_Eur)-SUM(Return_Value_Eur)) AS profit_
        , monthname(Order_Date) AS month_
   FROM returns, orders
   GROUP BY month_) z ON y.month_ = z.month_
```

I have the following code however I'm struggling with the profit table. This table should be a difference between the y.sales and x.returns. However the figures are coming up as follows, the profit column should be showing 394.

```
Month_      Returns_    Sales_   Profit_
January     108         502     -251
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic are all needed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix the old-school comma syntax for the join operation with the JOIN keyword; actually, just ditch the old-school comma syntax altogether for new queries.

Looks like the problem is the cartesian product of the join between `returns` and `orders`, the inline view returning "profit".

It's not clear what we are trying to achieve (broken SQL is like that, in that it fails to accurately communicate the actual specification)

It looks to me (and this is just a guess here) is that the intent is to subtract total returns from total sales, by month.

I'd do it like this:

```
SELECT v.month_
     , IFNULL( SUM(v.returns_) ,0)  AS returns_
     , IFNULL( SUM(v.sales_  ) ,0)  AS sales
     , IFNULL( SUM(v.sales_  ) ,0)
     - IFNULL( SUM(v.returns_) ,0)  AS net_
  FROM (
         SELECT 0.0                      AS sales_
              , SUM(r.return_value_eur)  AS returns_
              , MONTHNAME(r.return_date) AS month_
              , MONTH(r.return_date)     AS month_num
           FROM returns r
          GROUP
             BY MONTHNAME(r.return_date)
              , MONTH(r.return_date)

          UNION ALL

         SELECT SUM(o.total_price_eur)  AS sales_
              , 0.0                     AS returns_
              , MONTHNAME(o.order_date) AS month_
              , MONTH(o.order_date)     AS month_num
           FROM orders o
          GROUP
             BY MONTHNAME(o.order_date)
              , MONTH(o.order_date)
        ) v
  GROUP
     BY v.month_
      , v.month_num
  ORDER
     BY v.month_num
```

Note that this query ignores the year, which is a bit odd, mashing together November 2019, with November 2018, 2017, et al.

The example query orders rows by calendar order, January, February, March, ... that's the reason for the additional `month_num` column.

If there are no rows in `returns` or `orders` for a given month, then that month will not appear in the resultset.

---

To guarantee rows returned for all 12 calendar months, I would use row source that was guaranteed to return me one row for each month. Then do outer joins to aggregated returns by month and aggregated sales by month. (I'd also have the queries work with the integer value for the month, and then translate the integer to a string "month name" as a final output step.)

Something like this:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(c.month_num,'%m')) AS month_
     , IFNULL( tr.returns_ ) ,0)                AS returns_
     , IFNULL( ts.sales_   ) ,0)                AS sales_
     , IFNULL( ts.sales_   ) ,0)
     - IFNULL( tr.returns_ ) ,0)                AS net_
  FROM ( -- row source for calendar month 1..12
         SELECT 1 AS month_num UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4
         UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8
         UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12
       ) c
  LEFT
  JOIN ( -- total returns by month
         SELECT SUM(r.return_value_eur)  AS returns_
              , MONTH(r.return_date)     AS month_num
           FROM returns r
          GROUP
             BY MONTH(r.return_date)
       ) tr
    ON tr.month_num = c.month_num
  LEFT
  JOIN ( -- total orders by month 
         SELECT SUM(o.total_price_eur)  AS sales_
              , MONTH(o.order_date)     AS month_num
           FROM orders o
          GROUP
             BY MONTH(o.order_date)
       ) ts
    ON ts.month_num = c.month_num
 ORDER
    BY c.month_num
```